# Xcode 9 cannot go to method definition (Cocoa pods, Rxswift)

Tags: xcode9, rx-swift

I'm running into an issues with Xcode 9.

I have a new project setup with RxSwift 4.0 installed through CocoaPods.

The issues is I cannot go to method definition using command + click command

Xcode always display this error

[image]

Anyone know what is the error about and how we can resolve it in order to view the method definition (I believe it will be inside RxSwift Or RxCocoa pods).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is Xcode 9.0.1 bug, and has nothing to do with a particular framework, because in my case, it often happens even when Cmd+clicking on classes defined within the same project.

As for solution: just click on another file and then go back, popover will disappear. Then try again, sometimes it just works.

Also, keep an eye on Activity Monitor: after a while SourceKitService (part of Xcode 9) eats up a lot of memory (like 10+ Gb), in this case just Force Quit that SourceKitService process.